# Open Graph Insights: Definitions of "Objects" and "Actions"

Tags: object, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

When viewing insights for Open Graph, at the very bottom of the page we get the following:

1,193   App Created Actions?

> The number of Open Graph Actions created by this application.

and:

50,808  App Created Objects?

> The number of Open Graph Objects created by this application.

But what exactly are they, and how do they correlate? Actions are relatively obvious, they would cover the 'news.reads' and I had assumed objects would be the 'article' object you 'read'... but logic would dictate that you'd have a significantly lower number of objects than you would actions, rather than vice versa.

You'd think that 10 people might 'read' 1 article, thus giving you 10 actions against 1 object.

Have I misunderstood?